# basis of $W^\bot$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I'm having a problem solving those two small questions. I'll explain what I did and what I got, correct me if I did something wrong please.

1) let $W= \text{span} \{(2x+1,x^2)\}$ be a subspace of $R_3[x]$ with the inner integral product inside $[0,1]$. find a basis for $W^\bot$

2)let $W= \text{span}\{(1,i,1),(1+i,0,2)\}$ be a subspace of $C^3$. find a basis for $W^\bot$

what I did:

I've used gram-schmidt procedure on the spanning vectors of $W$ (in both questions) in order to obtain $W^\bot$ for 1)$\{40x^2-44x+9\}$ 2)$\{(1+i,1,-1)\}$

I think that the second one is correct, but the first one doesn't make any sense. do you get any other result?

Comment: Why doesn’t the first one make sense? It’s orthogonal to both of the spanning vectors for $W$, isn’t it? If by $\mathbb R_3[x]$ you mean the space of polynomials of degree *three* or less, however, $W^\perp$ is two-dimensional, so you’re still missing a vector.

Comment: actually you're right amd. i missed that. so in the case of 1), it cannot exist because to span $R_3[x]$ i need at least 3 vectors? so hence it cannot be a basis for $W^\bot$, is it right what i've said?

regarding 2) could you check that too please? your eyes are better than mine :-)

thank you very much for your reply

Comment: $\mathbb R_3[x]$ is *four* dimensional, $W$ is obviously two-dimensional, so $W^\perp$ is also two-dimensional. You need two vectors for a basis for it.